# OpenSSL Library and Header versions

Tags: php, windows, apache, openssl

I have the following stack.

Windows, Apache 2.4.57, OpenSSL 3.1.1
PHP 8.2.8

Trying to work with payment gateway that requires checking on the OpenSSL issue and it has been failing.

I found this and it seems to be the problem that cause the issue.

OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023

So it seems that I need to try different thing.

1. Set Apache OpenSSL to 3.0.8. I found one version of Apache, 2.4.55 that have Openssl 3.0.7 built in. But this defeats the purpose of upgrading Apache. I have tried downgrading, but will do so while I see whether there is anyone can help me with the second options.

This is last option because our security provider ask us to use 2.4.57 instead of 2.4.55.

2. Change openssl extension in PHP to support 3.1.1. I tried downloading it but cannot find it. If there is anyone who can help me and guide me on how to get php_openssl.dll to support that, it will be good.

Thanks.